# Chrome: window.content.document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension and I'm wondering what is the Chrome equivilant of `window.content.document`?

Comment: Are you talking about browser plugins?

Comment: @Tim Yes, sorry.. updated post

Comment: window.contentDocument ?

Comment: window.contentDocument is going to `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like crome extensions depend on script injection if you want to interact with pages:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

You can inject code or .js files.

For extension <-> DOM communication:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

To access windows: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html

Lets just say there's no direct access to DOM from Extension as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `window.content` in Chrome right now (August 2014)

but `window.document` works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like BGerrissen said, there is no direct access capability across different windows.
It is a restriction that different domain script cannot directly access each other.

As an extension, the main script itself is in a standalone chrome process.
You can put many functions, computations, preference code in this background.html.
And inject small portion of JS code into the content of other tab or window to manipulate the HTML content. And there communications to each other can be achieved by using postMessage and message handler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BGerrissen it correct. You need to communicate with web pages via a shared DOM using content scripts.

It's quite tricky, requiring you to register events and listeners and bind data to a DOM element that both scripts can access.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

There's an example in Google Chrome labs where an extension script makes a web page red:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#ede3c47b7757245be42ec33fd5ca63df4b490066